# Rate of change of acceleration

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, mass, acceleration

I am trying to figure out some equations for a program I'm writing and I'm kinda stuck. I don't have the best experience with math or science so bear with me here please.

I am trying to calculate trajectories of a rocket. And I'm taking it slow not considering atmospheric resistance for example. The rocket is losing mass as it's moving up and I have found the rate of change of the mass. However now I'm stuck trying to figure out the rate of change of acceleration.

From Newton we have $$\text{Acceleration} = (\text{Thrust} - \text{Weight})/\text{mass}$$ If I derive this equation I get

$${d(a) \over dt} = -{\text {Thrust}\over m^2}$$

I think I'm doing something wrong here. I am trying to create a connection between the rate of change of mass and the rate of change of acceleration. I want to avoid doing it numerically so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See the Rocket Equation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tsiolkovsky_rocket_equation

Comment: Have you ever had calculus classes?

Comment: A force divided by a squared mass does not have the same units as a rate of change of acceleration

Answer (score 1):

If your simulated rocket is burning fuel at a constant rate (a reasonable assumption), it is producing constant thrust, which is denoted by F.  Given this, you can expect the fuel to last for a given amount of time, which can be calculated by dividing the total starting fuel mass by the rate of burn.  Call this total time to burn the fuel $t_f$.  This leads to the following, which is based on Newton's 2nd law:

$a=F/m$

$m = m_{rocket} + m_{f0}(1-\frac{t}{t_f})$

where $m_{f0}$ is the starting mass of the fuel.  Therefore,

$a=F/[m_{rocket} + m_{f0}(1-\frac{t}{t_f})]$

Note: this isn't correcting for the retarding force of gravity, and that force will change its angle relative to the direction of the long axis of the rocket as the rocket ascends.  This means that if you intend to do somewhat realistic calculations, the math is going to get "messy", as I'm sure you found out if you followed the link recommended by Gert.